# Add a column based on the value of another column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to python. I encountered this task and was on it for a while without a clue.
Any suggestions can help! Thanks a lot.

I have a data frame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': ['Emo/3', 'Emo/4', 'Emo/1','Emo/3', '','Emo/3', 'Emo/4', 'Emo/1','Emo/3', '', 'Neu/5', 'Neu/2','Neu/5', 'Neu/2'],
        'Pos': ["repeat3", "repeat3", "repeat3", "repeat3", '',"repeat1", "repeat1", "repeat1", "repeat1", '', "repeat2", "repeat2","repeat2", "repeat2"],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    A       Pos
0   Emo/3   repeat3
1   Emo/4   repeat3
2   Emo/1   repeat3
3   Emo/3   repeat3
4       
5   Emo/3   repeat1
6   Emo/4   repeat1
7   Emo/1   repeat1
8   Emo/3   repeat1
9       
10  Neu/5   repeat2
11  Neu/2   repeat2
12  Neu/5   repeat2
13  Neu/2   repeat2
```

I want a output like this:

```
    A       Pos     B
0   Emo/3   repeat3 0
1   Emo/4   repeat3 0
2   Emo/1   repeat3 0
3   Emo/3   repeat3 0
4           
5   Emo/3   repeat1 1
6   Emo/4   repeat1 2
7   Emo/1   repeat1 3
8   Emo/3   repeat1 4
9           
10  Neu/5   repeat2 4
11  Neu/2   repeat2 2
12  Neu/5   repeat2 3
13  Neu/2   repeat2 1
```

The first four position of the column"B" is always 0. Then the other positions in the column "B" are based on the value in column"pos". if the row in column"pos" equal "repeat 1" then the column "B" at that four positions will be: 1, 2, 3, 4. If the row in column"pos" equal "repeat 2", then the column "B" at the four positions will be: 4, 3, 2, 1.

The values in Pos are always arranged as every four rows with the same value and the fifth row will be empty.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Generilized solution using Pandas tools

Ok it took me some time to figure it out but I wanted to find a slick answer and I kind of like this one:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['Emo/3', 'Emo/4', 'Emo/1','Emo/3', '','Emo/3', 'Emo/4', 'Emo/1','Emo/3', '', 'Neu/5', 'Neu/2','Neu/5', 'Neu/2', '', 'Neu/5', 'Neu/2','Neu/5', 'Neu/2'],
        'Pos': ["repeat3", "repeat3", "repeat3", "repeat3", '',"repeat1", "repeat1", "repeat1", "repeat1", '', "repeat2", "repeat2","repeat2", "repeat2", '', "repeat2", "repeat2","repeat2", "repeat2"],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#First we create column B and set first 4 value that are marked as repeat3 in 'Pos' column to zero
df['B']=df['Pos'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == "repeat3" else x)

#Then we create a boolean mask for the rows where 'Pos' is equal to repeat1
mask1=df['B'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == "repeat1"  else 0)
#Then we count how many blocks of type repeat1 we have
number_of_repeat1_blocks=int(mask1.sum()/4)
mask1=mask1.astype('bool')

#We do another mask the same for the rows where 'Pos' is equal to repeat2
mask2=df['B'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == "repeat2"  else 0).astype('bool')
#Then we count how many blocks of type repeat1 we have
number_of_repeat2_blocks=int(mask2.sum()/4)
mask2=mask2.astype('bool')


#We define the number sequence that you want to replace in each case
#For rows matchin repeat1
repl1= [1,2,3,4]*number_of_repeat1_blocks
#For rows matching repeat2
repl2= [4,3,2,1,]*number_of_repeat2_blocks

#Finally we simply replace the matched patterns
df.loc[mask1,'B'] = repl1
df.loc[mask2,'B'] = repl2


print(df)
```

---

Results:

```
        A      Pos  B
0   Emo/3  repeat3  0
1   Emo/4  repeat3  0
2   Emo/1  repeat3  0
3   Emo/3  repeat3  0
4                    
5   Emo/3  repeat1  1
6   Emo/4  repeat1  2
7   Emo/1  repeat1  3
8   Emo/3  repeat1  4
9                    
10  Neu/5  repeat2  4
11  Neu/2  repeat2  3
12  Neu/5  repeat2  2
13  Neu/2  repeat2  1
14                   
15  Neu/5  repeat2  4
16  Neu/2  repeat2  3
17  Neu/5  repeat2  2
18  Neu/2  repeat2  1
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I really like this methods. Though in my real dataframe I have multiple repeat 1 and repeat 2 blocks. for example: ``` 
9                 
10  Neu/5  repeat2
11  Neu/2  repeat2
12  Neu/5  repeat2
13  Neu/2  repeat2
14                
15  Neu/5  repeat2
16  Neu/2  repeat2
17  Neu/5  repeat2
18  Neu/2  repeat2``` It raise the error: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable. I have searched for a while to find a solution for this but failed. Do you have any insights?

Comment: yes sure you just count how many blocks of each you have and you change the size of the repl1 and repl2 lists. I ll update the reply. Please up vote my reply and accept the answer as  the one you prefer. Thanks!

Comment: @Catherine did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

I'm sure there's a better way, but here's one approach:

```py
df["B"] = ""
repeat_mapping = {"repeat3": [0]*4,
                  "repeat2": [*range(4, 0, -1)],
                  "repeat1": [*range(1, 5)]}

repeats = df[::5]["Pos"].map(repeat_mapping).explode()
repeats.index += pd.Series([*range(4)]*len(df[::5]))

df["B"][repeats.index] = repeats
```

Output:

```py
        A      Pos  B
0   Emo/3  repeat3  0
1   Emo/4  repeat3  0
2   Emo/1  repeat3  0
3   Emo/3  repeat3  0
4
5   Emo/3  repeat1  1
6   Emo/4  repeat1  2
7   Emo/1  repeat1  3
8   Emo/3  repeat1  4
9
10  Neu/5  repeat2  4
11  Neu/2  repeat2  3
12  Neu/5  repeat2  2
13  Neu/2  repeat2  1
```

### Steps

Prepare the new column:

```py
In [1]: df["B"] = ""

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
        A      Pos B
0   Emo/3  repeat3
1   Emo/4  repeat3
2   Emo/1  repeat3
3   Emo/3  repeat3
4
5   Emo/3  repeat1
6   Emo/4  repeat1
7   Emo/1  repeat1
8   Emo/3  repeat1
9
10  Neu/5  repeat2
11  Neu/2  repeat2
12  Neu/5  repeat2
13  Neu/2  repeat2
```

Grab each 5th row:

```py
In [3]: df[::5]["Pos"]
Out[3]:
0     repeat3
5     repeat1
10    repeat2
Name: Pos, dtype: object
```

Use `repeat_mapping`:

```py
In [4]: df[::5]["Pos"].map(repeat_mapping)
Out[4]:
0     [0, 0, 0, 0]
5     [1, 2, 3, 4]
10    [4, 3, 2, 1]
Name: Pos, dtype: object
```

Explode lists:

```py
In [5]: repeats = df[::5]["Pos"].map(repeat_mapping).explode()

In [6]: repeats
Out[6]:
0     0
0     0
0     0
0     0
5     1
5     2
5     3
5     4
10    4
10    3
10    2
10    1
Name: Pos, dtype: object
```

Notice each index in `repeats` is repeated 4 times. We'll fix this by incrementing each index by `0, 1, 2, 3`:

```py
In [7]: pd.Series([*range(4)]*len(df[::5])).values
Out[7]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)

In [8]: repeats.index += pd.Series([*range(4)]*len(df[::5]))

In [9]: repeats
Out[9]:
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
5     1
6     2
7     3
8     4
10    4
11    3
12    2
13    1
Name: Pos, dtype: object
```

Finally, `df["B"][repeats.index]` only selects the rows whose index matches the indices of `repeats`, to which we then assign the values of `repeats`.